# Как получить доступ к атрибутам объекта в результате запроса?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть объектный тип:

```
create or replace type nt1 is table of varchar2 (8)
/
create or replace type o1 as object (
    id int,
    dt date, names nt1)
/
```

В пакете определена функция, которая возвращает экземплар этого объект:

```
function geto1 (id int) return o1 is  
begin
    return o1 (id, sysdate, nt1 ('abc','def','zyx'));
end;
/
```

Всё компилируется, но когда пытаюсь выполнить функцию и получить возвращаемые ею значения:

```
select p1.geto1 (1) result from dual;
```

то получаю вывод как:

> [P1.O1]

А как мне получить значения этого объекта, то есть, его атрибуты?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/69302379

Answer (score 2):

Значение экземплара объекта возвращаются в виде аналогичной структуры данных на ЯП, на котором написан инструмент посылающий запросы.

Различные инструменты по разному отображают результат запроса с комплексными типами данных, например, SQL*Plus покажет тот же результат уже более информативно:

```
RESULT
----------------------------------------------------------------
O1(1, '2021-09-24 20:50:02', NT1('abc', 'def', 'zyx'))
```

Чтобы не полагаться на то, как инструмент отобразит результат, надо явно указать атрибуты объекта:

```
select q.fun.id, q.fun.dt, q.fun.names 
from (
    select p1.geto1 (1) fun from dual) q;

     FUN.ID FUN.DT              FUN.NAMES                       
---------- ------------------- --------------------------------
         1 2021-09-24 21:51:21 NT1('abc', 'def', 'zyx')
```

Заметьте, чтобы получить доступ к атрибутам объекта, надо указывать полное квалифицированное имя, например, `<alias>.<column>.<attribute>`.

Осталось получить значения вложенной таблицы, обычное корреляционное соединение:

```
select q.fun.id, q.fun.dt, column_value name   
from (
    select geto1 (1) fun from dual) q, table (q.fun.names);

    FUN.ID FUN.DT              NAME    
---------- ------------------- --------
         1 2021-09-24 21:57:13 abc     
         1 2021-09-24 21:57:13 def     
         1 2021-09-24 21:57:13 zyx
```